# Linked list; TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I'm studying linked lists in Python 3.11. I wrote code given in the book. Code is below:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node.data)
            node = node.next

    def append(self, data):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = Node(data)
            return
        current = self.head
        while current.next:
            current = current.next
        current.next = Node(data)

    def search(self, target):
        current = self.head
        while current.next:
            if current.data == target:
                return True
            else:
                current = current.next
        return False

    def remove(self, target):
        if self.head == target:
            self.head = self.head.next
            return
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            if current.data == target:
                previous.next = current.next
            previous = current
            current = current.next

    def reverse_list(self):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            next = current.next
            current.next = previous
            previous = current
            current = next
        self.head = previous

a_list = LinkedList()
a_list.append("Tuesday")
a_list.append("Wednesday")
print(a_list)

import random

a_list = LinkedList()

for i in range(0, 20):
    j = random.randint(1, 30)
    a_list.search(j)
    print(j, end=' ')
```

When I run this code, error appears:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File linked_list.py, line 62, in 
print(a_list)
TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

Since the problem in function **str**, I tried following (adding return in the end):
1)

```
def __str__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node.data)
            node = node.next
        return node
```

The result is the same:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File linked_list.py, line 62, in 
print(a_list)
TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

2)

```
def __str__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node.data)
            node = node.next
        return node.data
```

The result:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "linked_list.py", line 63, in 
print(a_list)
File "linked_list.py", line 18, in **str**
return node.data
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: When you override \_\_str__ you *must* return str type

Comment: You have taken the right steps towards an answer, but now the previous attempts are not relevant to the remaining problem, and the last step is a simple logical oversight that does not merit a question. Think carefully about the loop. If you do `while node is not None:`, what do you know about the `node` *after* the loop? Does it make sense to use `.data` on that result? The purpose of the loop is to find the "last" node, right? Can you think of something interesting that is true about that node? Do you see how you can use this to fix the loop condition?

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. We require **one** issue per question; the purpose here **is not** to talk through a problem you were solving and have others help you the rest of the way. The purpose is to publish something that can help build a searchable library.

Comment: Putting `print` inside `__str__` doesn't mean that `__str__` will return the things that get printed. Returning and printing are separate. Use the loop to build up a string and return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one problem in your code:

- The issue you ask about: the author of the `__str__` mistakenly thought that it should *print* the content of the list. This is not the purpose of `__str__`. Instead, it should return a string version of the list. It is up to the caller to do something with this string, which *could* be printing it or something else.

  A quick fix would be to replace the `print` calls with code that concatenates the data into a string and then returns it:

  ```py
  def __str__(self):
      s = ""
      node = self.head
      while node is not None:
          s += f"{node.data} "  # don't print, but collect in a string
          node = node.next
      return s
  ```

  This is not the most elegant way to do it though. You could benefit from first defining `__iter__`, which is useful for other purposes as well...
- `search` has a condition where it checks `current.next` but without ensuring that `current` is not `None`. So this code will run into an error when the list is empty.  And secondly, it will not find a match when the last node (only) has the searched data. The condition should be on `current`, not `current.next`
- `remove` compares `head` with `target`, and also `current.data` with `target`. This is inconsistent. Either the function is called with a node instance, or with data. Now you have a mix. I suppose you wanted `remove` to be called with *data*, and so the first `if` statement is wrong. You should first check if the list has a node and then check the data of the head node.
- `remove` continues the loop after it has deleted a node, trying to find more matches. That is fine, but it is not consistent with how you deal with a match in the head node, because there you exit the function when there is a match. To be consistent, you should not exit there, and keep going (both checking the head, and later the rest of the nodes).
- When `remove` finds a match in the loop, it updates `previous` to be the deleted node. This is not correct. For instance, it will mean that only one of two consecutive matching nodes is deleted. When you have a match, `previous` should remain unchanged and refer to the node that preceded the now deleted node.

Not a problem, but:

- The driver code calls `a_list.search(j)` but doesn't do anything with the returned value, and so it is useless.
- That random "test" doesn't add any nodes to the list -- it remains empty. It would have made more sense if the random values were *added* to the list, after which you could do some positive and negative tests of the `search` method.
- The name `search` does not reveal that it returns a boolean (and not a node or position). Call it `has` or `includes` or `contains`. Or even better, define `__contains__`, so that you can use the `in` operator instead. Or still better: when you have defined `__iter__` it will be used to interpret the `in` operator, and so you can actually drop this `search` method completely.
- The addition of `_list` in the name `reverse_list` is unnecessary. This is a method on a linked list, so it is evident that the reversal concerns a (linked) list.

Here is suggested code for the `LinkedList` class:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __iter__(self):  # Make linked list iterable. Also supports IN operator
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.data
            node = node.next
    
    def __str__(self):  # Don't print, but return str
        # Make use of __iter__
        return " ".join(map(str, self))

    def append(self, data):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = Node(data)
            return
        current = self.head
        while current.next:
            current = current.next
        current.next = Node(data)

    def remove(self, target):
        # Check in a loop, and don't return:
        while self.head and self.head.data == target:  # compare data, not node
            self.head = self.head.next
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            if current.data == target:
                previous.next = current.next
            else:  # Only update previous when there is no match
                previous = current
            current = current.next

    def reverse(self):  # Better name
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            next = current.next
            current.next = previous
            previous = current
            current = next
        self.head = previous
```

Driver code could be:

```
a_list = LinkedList()
a_list.append("Tuesday")
a_list.append("Wednesday")
a_list.append("Wednesday")
a_list.append("Thursday")
print(a_list)
a_list.remove("Wednesday")
print("Does it have Tuesday? ", "Tuesday" in a_list)
print(*a_list)
```